# Does Bigquery support PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, google-bigquery, wrapper

My organisation is considering moving reporting and data analysis to Google Bigquery from MySQL. Some of the tables in MySQL are populated using PDO in PHP, after reading data from third party APIs.

Originally, I created my scripts on MS SQL database and migrating to MySQL was as easy as just changing the connection parameters, but can that be done for Bigquery as well? Are there any PDO wrappers available for Bigquery?

I googled and saw some direct BQ APIs to load tables and stuff, but was not able to find a more scalable solution for PHP where I could just migrate my existing code.

Comment: No. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php

Comment: @Phil I saw that link, so there is no PHP PDO support for now?

Comment: I'd say never unless somebody creates a C library and then writes a PDO driver using that. There's very little incentive for such a thing to happen given there's already a vendor supported PHP library available

Comment: @Phil May I ask you to post the comment as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: I've filed a feature request at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/1014 to add support for this.

Answer (score 1):

No. [See](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php).

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/1014) in Github for it.